# Resharper NUnit Test Runner not breaking on unhandled exceptions

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit, resharper, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

When I run a nunit test in debug mode (<kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> in Resharper), and some unhandled exception occurs, the debugger doesn't break and jump to the error in the code. Instead, the output window is filled with errors like

```
Exception thrown: 'NUnit.Framework.AssertionException' in nunit.framework.dll 
  //              ^^^^^^^ This is the actual exception that I want to break on.
  // Can be any exception inside my test method, e.g. also a null reference exception.
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'NUnit.Core.NUnitException' in nunit.core.dll
The thread 'NUnit Reporter' (0x37f4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 'Runner thread' (0x33b8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.EndOfStreamException' in JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.dll
The program '[10008] JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR45.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

When I place a breakpoint somewhere, the debugger correctly breaks and jumps. When I check all CLR Exceptions in the Exception Settings, the debugger does break, but it breaks also on handled exceptions, which I don't want, and the errors posted above still occur.

What is going wrong here?

**Update**

When enabling *Just My Code*, the list of errors reduces to

```
Exception thrown: 'NUnit.Framework.AssertionException' in nunit.framework.dll
An exception of type 'NUnit.Framework.AssertionException' occurred in nunit.framework.dll but was not handled in user code
The thread 'NUnit Reporter' (0x5288) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Runner thread' (0x61ec) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[22972] JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR45.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

but still no breakage on the exception.

Comment: Such exceptions are first chance exceptions. They are properly handled (by NUnit), and of course won't let Visual Studio break on them.

Comment: So they don't have anything to do with the issue I'm trying to solve? That's good to know.

Comment: You will have to tell more about that "unhandled exception". At least from the log portion you pasted, there is no such exception.

Comment: It is the first exception in the log. Updated post to include a comment.

Comment: Could you check whether "Just my code" is enabled? I don't know how it works with respect to exception configuration that you described..

Comment: @Matthias It is not. Should it be?

Comment: Try =) NUnit is non-user code....

Comment: OP  has been updated.

Comment: Were you able to figure out where in the code it was throwing the exception?